# Indexing a value within a table function

Tags: list-manipulation

Is what I'm looking to do possible?  I know that I can get it to work with a for loop, but a table would make things much neater.

What I need to do while calculation the table below is to reset the variable `l` such that `l = l - fretScale[y_]`.  `l` is initially set to 25.

```
l = 25 ;(* Nominal string length *)

fretScale[y_] := l*(1 - 1/2^(1/12)) // N;

Table[fretScale[y], {y, 1, 30, 1}]
```

What I did with the for loop (which works is this:

```
For[i = 1; y = 0, i < n + 1, i++, 
  y = l*(1 - 1/2^(1/12)) // N; 
  l = l - y
```

(Note, in the loop `fretScale[y_]` is defined as y, not as a defined function)

The table function above calculates the correct first fret position of 1.403, but keeps `l` fixed at 25 and I need to successively make `l` range from 25, 23.597, 22.273,...

The output I get for the table is:

```
{1.40314, 1.40314, 1.40314, ...}
```

what I want (and get for the for loop is)

```
{1.40314, 2.72753, 3.97759, ...}
```

Comment: `k[x_] := x - x*(1 - 1/2^(1/12)) // N;
NestList[k, 25, 10]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one of many ways to do it with `Table`.

```
l = 25;
k = 1/2^(1/12) // N;
l - Table[l = k l, {30}]
```

> ```
> {1.40314, 2.72753, 3.97759, 5.15749, 6.27116, 7.32233, 8.3145, 9.25099, 10.1349, 
>  10.9692, 11.7567, 12.5, 13.2016, 13.8638, 14.4888, 15.0787, 15.6356, 16.1612, 
>  16.6573, 17.1255, 17.5675, 17.9846, 18.3784, 18.75, 19.1008, 19.4319, 19.7444, 
>  20.0394, 20.3178, 20.5806}
> ```

Comment: ...and since it's all exponential: `25. Table[1 - 2^(-k/12), {k, 30}]`

Comment: @J.M.isback. Sure, that's another of the countless (well, I can't count them) of doing this with `Table`. BTW, glad to see you back.